# geom_signif in facet_wrap in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom

I'm trying to ggplot2 as facet_wrap box plot, but I'm having trouble in few things:
1- triangle symbol isn't showing in the graph but it shows in the environment window and console
2- in facet_wrap I'm using theme_lindraw and I want to remove x axis labels and leave it at the bottom panel only
3- I want to add geom_signif for each panel separately but it keeps labelling all panels same annotations which I don't want
4- How to increase y axis to have a space between annotations and the border of the plot

here's my coding

```
strains<-rep(c("wt","dfg1\u25b3","asd1\u25b3","dfg1\u25b3 asd1\u25b3"),each=6)
x<-rep(c("0mM","4mM"),each=3)
y<-c(12,12.91,12.5,15,15.1,14,12,12.2,12.3,15.,15.3,15.9,7.1,7.7,7.3,11.5,11.6,11.1,7.5,7.4,7.3,12,11,10)
df<-data.frame(x,y,strains)
df$strains<-factor(df$strains,levels = c("wt","dfg1\u25b3","asd1\u25b3","dfg1\u25b3 asd1\u25b3"),ordered = TRUE)

ggplot(df)+
  aes(x=x,y=y,fill=x)+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("omM","4mM"),c("omM","4mM"),c("omM","4mM"),c("omM","4mM")), map_signif_level = TRUE,annotations = c("*","**","**","*"),y=c(16,17,12,13))+
  facet_wrap(~strains,scales = "free",ncol = 1)+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("("*mu~"m)")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("0mM"="gray","4mM"="pink"))+
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 16)+
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),legend.position = "none",strip.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))
```

[image]

attached image to clarify what I did and what codes aren't working

Comment: Is it when you save the plot that there's no `△` and if so which format are you saving to - I'm guessing pdf?

Comment: it's not, its before the saving

Comment: anyone can help with geom_signif?